# Delphi: Why VCL is not thread-safe? How can be?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, vcl

Everywhere is noticed that VCL is not thread-safe and we must synchronize access to it. So it's VCL faults that is not thread-safe.

How VCL itself can be thread-safe?

Comment: Imagine you're a window.  Imagine two threads are telling you to do something different at the same time.  What do you do?  One is in the middle of telling you to repaint yourself when another suddenly changes your XY coordinates.  What happens?  This is one of many examples - there are countless other ways that this can go wrong.  The complexity and overhead required to get around all of these issues would almost certainly be a total nightmare.  Effectively, the VCL probably cannot be made threadsafe.

Comment: Combine what David said with what J commented above and you might get the picture. Imagine your wife and all your children (girlfriend and mom) speaking to you all at once expecting you to answer them all at once. What a mess. The same with the visual side of a windows gui app. The visual controls will have a hack of a time to try and figure out what every thread wants

Comment: To get even a clearer picture you would have to first do a search on how threads are given time slices. Each thread only has a certain amount of CPU time that is allocated to it and if a thread has not finished doing what it wanted to do then it has to wait for the next turn it gets. In the meanwhile some other thread may decide to do something else with the VCL and that is basically a no-no! So what is left to do? They have to synchronize access to the VCL

Comment: The main point remains that the visual side of a GUI app is only one thing. Threads are not just one thing. They might be many things. Think about having only one toilet in your house. Only one is allowed on it at any given time. What a mess it will be if two people tried to use it at the same time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What, precisely, does "thread-safe" mean to you? What about someone else? Every time I see this brought up, it ends up boiling down to this: "I want VCL to be thread-safe so I don't have to think about threading and synchronization issues. I want to write my code as if it is still single-threaded."

No matter how much work went into making VCL so-called "thread-safe", there will always be situations where you can get into trouble. How would *you* go about making it thread-safe? I don't say this to be combative, rather I merely want to demonstrate that it is not a simple problem with a simple, "works-in-all-cases" solution. To highlight this, let's look at some potential "solutions."

The simplest and most direct approach I see is each component has some kind of "lock", say a mutex or critical section. Every method on the component grabs the lock on entry and then releases the lock just prior to exit. Let's continue down this path with a [thought experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment). Consider how Windows processes messages:

Main thread obtains a message from the message queue and then dispatches it to the appropriate WndProc. This message is then routed to the appropriate TWinControl component. Since the component has a "lock", as the message is routed to the appropriate message handler on the component, the lock is acquired. So far so good.

Now take the proverbial button-click message processing. The OnClick message handler is now called which will most likely be a method on the owning TForm. Since the TForm descendant is also a TWinControl component, the TForm's lock is now acquired while the OnClick handler is processed. Now the button component is locked and the TForm component is also locked.

Continuing on this line of thinking, suppose the OnClick handler now wants add an item to a listbox, listview, or some other visual list or grid component. Now suppose some other thread (not the main UI thread) is already in the midst of accessing this same component. Once a method is called on the list from the UI thread it will attempt to acquire the lock, which it cannot since the other thread is currently holding it. As long as the non-UI thread doesn't hold that lock for very long, the UI thread will only block for a brief period.

So far so good, right? Now suppose, that while the non-UI thread is holding the list control's lock, a notification event is called. Since, it will most likely be a method on the owning TForm, upon entry to the event handler, the code will attempt to acquire the lock for the TForm.

Do you see the problem? Remember the button OnClick handler? It *already* has the TForm lock in the UI thread! It is now blocked waiting for the lock on the list control, which the non-UI thread owns. **This is a classic dead-lock.** Thread A holds lock A and attempts to acquire lock B which is held by thread B. Thread B is at the same time attempting to acquire lock A.

Clearly, if every control/component has a lock that is automatically acquired and released for every method isn't a solution. What if we left the locking up to the user? Do you see how that also doesn't solve the problem either? How can you be certain that all the code you have (including any third-party components) properly locks/unlocks the controls/components? How does this keep the above scenario from happening?

What about a single shared lock for the whole of VCL? In this scenario, for each message that is processed, the lock is acquired while the message is processed regardless of what component the message is routed to. Again, how does this solve a similar scenario I described above? What if the user's code added other locks for synchronization with other non-UI threads? Even the simple act of blocking until a non-UI thread terminates can cause a dead lock if it is done while the UI thread holds the VCL lock.

What about non-UI components? Database, serial, network, containers, etc...? How should they be handled?

As excellently explained by the other answers, Windows already does a pretty decent job of properly segregating UI message processing to only the thread on which each HWND is created. In fact, learning precisely how Windows works in this regard will go a long way to understanding how you can write your code to work with Windows and VCL in a manner that avoids most of the pitfalls I highlighted above. The bottom line is writing multi-threaded code is difficult, requires a rather drastic mental shift, and lots of practice. Read as much as you can on multi-threading from as many sources as possible. Learn and understand as many coding examples of "thread-safe" code as you can, in any language.

Hopefully this was informative.

Comment: Thanks, the lock concept is a good example. In the last paragraph you didn't answer the question "What about non-UI components?". Also where "The bottom line..." point to?

Comment: @SAMPro That was a rhetorical question.

Comment: The lock concept was presented as an example of why it is hard (nigh impossible) to get a general solution and has its own serious ramifications.

Comment: there is something like VCL that is thread-safe (in a different programming language, Linux, Mac)?

Answer (score 7):

The VCL is not thread safe. It is a wrapper around Win32. Win32 is thread safe but has threading rules that give meaning to that statement. Most specifically a window has affinity to the thread that created it.

The design of the Windows message queue means that it is almost always preferable to have all your GUI windows created by the main thread. The VCL designers decided that it was reasonable only to support that mode of operation. And so all VCL code must be executed from the main thread.

There's nothing that can be done to change this. This is by design. If you wish to execute VCL code, it must be done on the main thread. Use `TThread.Synchronize` or `TThread.Queue` to arrange that.

Comment: I don't understand first statement of second paragraph "The design of the Windows message queue means...".

Comment: Input messages are posted to the message queue of the thread that owns the window. If you have multiple gui threads then they all need message pumps and the order of messages is unpredictable. Everything gets outrageously complicated. And for what gain. VCL requires use of main thread. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of reasons why the VCL (especially UI controls) is not thread safe.

1. Race conditions on message input, especially in code that directly calls `TControl.Perform()`/`TObject.Dispatch()` instead of using `PostMessage()`/`SendMessage()`.  The former does not perform any synchronizing of the control's message handlers, but the latter does. So it is not safe to perform non-HWND based messages from outside of the main thread.
2. An HWND has thread affinity. It receives and processes messages only on, and can be destroyed only on, the thread context that creates it.  A `TWinControl` can destroy and recreate its HWND at any time, even multiple times, during its lifetime. The `TWinControl.Handle` property getter creates a new HWND if none exists yet. So if the control is in the process of recreating its HWND when another thread reads from the `Handle` property, the control can end up with a new HWND that was created in the wrong thread context, making the control no longer responsive to the main message loop (and can potentially leak a second HWND as well).  So it is not safe to read from the `TWinControl.Handle` property from outside of the main thread.
3. The VCL has a `MakeObjectInstance()` function that creates a dynamic proxy to allow a `TWndMethod` class method to be used as a Win32 `WNDPROC` window callback procedure. All `TWinControl` controls, and some utility classes like `TTimer`, use this function.  Internally, it maintains a global linked list of proxies, and that list is not protected from concurrent access across threads. So it is not safe to create/destroy HWND-based VCL controls from outside of the main thread.

I'm sure there are other reasons, but these are the big ones.

Comment: The first two are biggies, the third could trivially be solved with serialization

Comment: Thanks, I have a side question: why a control destroy its HWND and recreate it? Also is only the HWND that I must don't read from it outside of main thread or I should also don't read from any component outside of main thread?

Comment: Window re-creation is needed, for instance, when a VCL property is changed that can only be applied at window creation time. An example is window owner. Some properties/methods are fine from non GUI threads. No simple rule though. If you would separate your UI from your app's logic in a clean way you wouldn't need to worry about any of this

Comment: @David, thanks a lot. But how can I know that properties/methods are fine to access from non GUI threads?

Comment: You need a deep understanding of Win32 and the VCL and threading. What you should be asking yourself is why your threads are getting involved in the GUI. Once you realise that is a mistake, and design your application better, then you'll find that this entire issue dissolves into nothing.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25 even though that code uses a thread, it needs to sync with the main thread (but isn't) when accessing the GUI. It is not really a good example of a useful thread since the same work can also be done using a UI timer instead.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25 only if you block the main message loop. Using a timer or thread does not do that. But using a thread to update the UI in a loop is not a very useful thread. A UI timer will work better in that case.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25 then neither will a thread, since the main message loop will be blocked from processing sync requests to access the UI safely from a thread. You need to rethink your startup logic.

Comment: I haven't seen the splash screen freezing/flickering but this is probably because I have MANY but SMALL initializations. But you are right. So, tanks. I will consider that.