# Is it safe to read values from a thread without synchronize?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, vcl

I was wondering if it's safe to **read** values from a VCL control outside the main thread.

Let's say I read line after line (or it's caption property) from a `TMemo/TEdit` control from a thread (without `TThread.Synchronize`), **but also made sure** the `TMemo/TEdit` control has been disabled and/or it's read only flag has been enabled.

Would it be safe?

Comment: Read [Delphi: Why VCL is not thread-safe? How can be?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28655758/576719) and see why accessing a VCL control from a thread that is not the main thread is a no-no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not safe. The content from memo and edit controls is read by calling the window procedure (using the `Perform` method), passing `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and `WM_GETTEXT`. Such code is required by Win32 to be executed on the thread that created the window, in this case the main thread. So when you read the `Text` property from a worker thread, you break that rule, because you call `Perform` on the worker thread, and then execute the window procedure on the wrong thread.

You might instead think that you could use `SendMessage` passing `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH/WM_GETTEXT` to arrange that the window procedure was executed on the main thread. But that is subject to a nasty race condition. You need a window handle to use `SendMessage`, but accessing the `Handle` property on the worker thread is not threadsafe. That must be done on the main thread, otherwise VCL window re-creation can lead to the window being created by your worker thread. And GUI windows must be created by the main thread.

Comment: So in order to access it's content, do I need to copy it? Or is is there any other way to access the content without using additional memory...? Synchronize would be a waste in resources as well...

Comment: So I have to Synchronize every time I need to read a new line from a Memo control... Thank you for your answer

Comment: Why would that be troublesome though. It's user interface. Performance is limited by the ability of the user to interact with the UI.

Comment: It's a little bit off-topic but what about vars declared in the public/private/published section of a TForm... ? Are those safe to access from a thread?

Comment: It all depends what you do with them, what the types are, what modifies then, and so on.

Comment: I think you mean WM_GETTEXT. It works across process boundary, why should it not work across thread boundary?

Comment: @sertac VCL window recreation can lead to the window being recreated on the wrong thread

Comment: @David - Would reading WindowHandle be unsafe? If not HandleAllocated could be called beforehand.

Comment: @sertac Definitely unsafe. Re-creation can happen at any time. No synchronisation of that with workers. HandleAllocated could be true. But by the time you read Handle it could have been destroyed as part of re-creation cycle. Since the read needs to take place on main thread you may as well synchronise to it anyway. It's going to happen come what may. So may as well do it safely!

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, even posting messages to a form through its handle is unsafe for the same reason. Thats why one must post it to a separate allocated handle and redirect the message from there.

Comment: @LURD - That's an interesting point, which does not depend on threading at all. Any recreation can render queued, but not retrieved messages orphaned. VCL, particularly Vcl.Forms, use PostMessage extensively. I guess that's a risk VCL developers considered ignorable.

Comment: "Close; RecreateWnd;" for instance fails to close a secondary form that specifies caFree as close action.

Comment: That's a very good point. Probably a reason why the VCL has evolved over the years to use recreation as little as possible.

Comment: @David, I would totally agree that you should read the text from the main thread only. Meanwhile I do not think that your answer is exact. First of all it is safe to send/post messages to a window from any thread (the message will be placed to the window queue and it will be handled in the thread where the control window was created). In other words SendMessage will synchronize the current thread with main.
The second point is that memo does not send the message, it calls Perform. Actually it calls the message handler directly (without message queue). That's why it is not safe.

Comment: @Max Some of your details are wrong. Sent messages dont get placed on the queue. It's the act of getting the handle that is the problem, not sending the message. But if Perform is called then it would be called on the wrong thread wouldn't it. Which is probably a key point that I'd missed. I'll check that out. Thanks.

Comment: @David, sorry but I do not understand what's wrong in my message, I would appreciate if you could point it out for me. I would say that "the act of getting handle" is just your assumption for the code which was not posted in the original question. Your assumption has no effect if you pass the handler as a parameter to the the thread which is created in main thread for example and you are sure the handle is not recreated. I think you should remove "sending a WM_GETTEXT message" from you answer, on the one hand message is not sent, on the other hand send message is thread safe

Comment: @Max Sending a message is threadsafe, but getting the window handle is not threadsafe. You are quite right about `Perform`. I've update the answer. Thanks.