# Form.ShowModal not working on TThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have the following class

```
type TMyThread = class(TThread)
form: TForm;
procedure Execute; override;
constructor Create();
end;

procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
inherited;
form.ShowModal;
end;

constructor MyThread.Create;
begin
inherited Create(true);
form := TForm.CreateNew(nil);
end;
```

Then I execute the following code:

```
var
thread: TMyThread;
begin
thread := MyThread.Create;
thread.Resume; //I know its depracated
readln;
end;
```

I should expect a form window appearing, instead nothing happens. When debugging i can see that a new thread has spawned with the form but I can't see it anywere. I've tried giving the form all the properties it needs but still nothing. Form.Show doen't help neither. But when trying the following:

```
begin
thread.form := TForm.CreateNew(nil);
thread.form.ShowModal;
end.
```

A new form is created and shown as expected. Why do I want to create a form in a TThread? Because I want to have my console and my form in my application work asynchronously. Is there something inherently wrong in trying to do that? An easier way that doesn't involve using threads?

Comment: I would never ever let the worker thread (created by me) control the UI of the application (it's not techically impossible, but a very bad design signal).

Comment: Hi Victoria, thanks for the answer, why do you think so? What would be a better option instead?

Comment: As Victoria said, never ever create a form in a thread or try to access the GUI from a thread outside of a TThread.Synchronize procedure.  You can create and show as any forms as you like.  Just do a form.Show; instead of a form.ShowModal;

Comment: You cannot access the VCL from threads directly (except the main thread) .. This is well documented. Use File->New->Other, create a new TThread object from the Object Repository, and then read the large auto-generated comment that is added at the top of that unit. Then read all of the Delphi documentation related to TThread, which stresses not accessing the VCL directly from your thread. Then Google *delphi VCL thread* and read the dozens and dozens of results, all of which say you can't access the VCL directly from your thread. Neither the VCL or FMX are thread safe.

Comment: See [Delphi: Why VCL is not thread-safe? How can be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28655758/62576) and its accepted answer.

Comment: TDC As I said above Form.Show and ShowModal  don't work in this case.
@KenWhite Thanks for your answer, I see why It is a bad practice, is there any alternative way I can accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I can't suggest an alternative, because I don't know what *my console and my form in my application work asynchronously* means. It might be better to delete this question and start over with a more specific question about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain my statement:  just create the form(s) and .Show them from the main form, not from a thread.  Just create the form(s) and call show.

Comment: @GerardMarquina as others have said, you cannot show your Form directly from a thread like you are doing. The thread would need to synchronize access to the UI. Please edit your question to show your intended use of such a thread. That would provide more context in which people can possibly show you alternative solutions.