# How to create forms via thread to make application startup fast

Tags: delphi

When our application has only around 50 forms, the application starts OK, but now that we have around 130 forms, it has 3 to 4 seconds delay before application starts. Most of our forms are created in the main unit :

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TFormLogIn, formLogIn);
 // more forms..

  Application.Run;
end.
```

I tried putting the creation of most forms in a thread

> (thread will start after user sucessfully login)

but the application freezes after login. If I call ***synchronize(CreateForms)*** then application will run smooth but is delayed again by 3 to 4 seconds. here is my code to create forms in a thread :

```
TIniThread = class(TThread)
  private
  procedure CreateForms;
  protected
  procedure Execute; override;
  end;


{ TIniThread }

procedure TIniThread.CreateForms;
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
end;

procedure TIniThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  CreateForms;
//  Synchronize(CreateForms);

end;
```

So how can I put the creation of forms in a thread to make application start fast again?

Comment: You should create forms as you need them, and destroy them when you don't..

Comment: I understand. I have considered it as last option because its too much to adjust.. if there are other options then it would be great..

Comment: Last option it is, you can't do threaded VCL, *synchronize*d code runs in the main thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655758/delphi-why-vcl-is-not-thread-safe-how-can-be

Comment: @Ago updating 130 forms for on-demand creation and on-close destruction should not take very long, maybe a few hours, or a day. Don't consider it a last resort, you should just do it and be done with it. The only form that should EVER be auto-created at startup is the MainForm. If you are not destroying forms because they carry state data between shows, you haven't separated your data from your UI adequately enough, if at all. You can always initialize your *data* in threads if needed, but not UIs. No user wants to see 130 forms at a time, so don't waste memory for forms that are not visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, your plan to move form creation code into a thread can not work. That's because of the VCL threading model. All form code that operates on the underlying window must be executed in the main user thread.

The actual problem you have is that you create all the forms in your program at startup. If you want to make significant improvements then you will need a redesign. Create each form on demand.