# Why TApplication.MessageBox closes automatically?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, backgroundworker, splash-screen, tform

I have an app that takes a few seconds to load (lots of initializations). The GUI freezes during startup. So I want to create a splash screen that fades in and out as the application loads.
I use [TBackgroundWorker](http://www.delphiarea.com/downloads/?dl_cat=4&dl_search=back) component to do the animation in a background thread.

However, something strange happens when I use this component: when it signals "work complete" (see BackgroundWorkerWorkComplete) a message dialog that I open meanwhile is automatically closed.

```
procedure TMainForm.ButtonStartSplashClick(Sender: TObject);
VAR
  frmSplash: TfrmSplash;
begin
 frmSplash:= TfrmSplash.Create(NIL);
 frmSplash.StartAnimation;

 //MessageBox(Handle, 'Hi', nil, MB_OK);   // This remains on screen
 Application.MessageBox(PChar('Hi'), PChar('Box'), MB_ICONINFORMATION); // This is automatically closed when the background thread is done
end;
```

---

And this is the splash screen:

```
procedure TfrmSplash.StartAnimation;
begin
 Show;
 BackgroundWorker.Execute;
end;


procedure TfrmSplash.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 Action:= caFree;
end;


procedure TfrmSplash.BackgroundWorkerWork(Worker: TBackgroundWorker);
VAR i: Integer;
begin
  for i:= 1 to 255 DO
   begin
    AlphaBlendValue:= i; // do not access GUI directly from thread
    Sleep(30);
   end;
end;


procedure TfrmSplash.BackgroundWorkerWorkComplete(Worker: TBackgroundWorker; Cancelled: Boolean);
begin
 Close; // At this point, the msg box will be closed also
end;
```

What I find strange is that MessageBox remains on screen while Application.MessageBox does not (is automatically closed).

Why closing TfrmSplash will close the message box also?

Comment: Did you read the docs? 
"You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your {OnWork} event handler." 
Does it still happen when you don't set AlphaBlendValue?

Comment: Just tested. Still happens. I would expect to get some random AV because of the GUI access. But anyway, that is not the cause since it sill happens after I comment out AlphaBlendValue:= i

Comment: use the report progress event for your AlphaBlend code.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout - good idea. thanks/+1. but this will not solved the disappearing msgbox oddity.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout For that use case, I'd just use a `TTimer`, to be honest.  No point spinning up a thread just to block a busy loop creating simple events at a regular interval.

Comment: @J... It has to be in a bkg thread not in a timer. I have to do lots of initializations. If you use a timer, the animation will be choppy, as the program loads. Plus that the splash form is reusable :)

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25 All we can see is the code in the question - for that code, a TTimer would do the same thing as using the report progress handler.  If your real code is different, only you can decide what makes sense - we can't see it.

Comment: @J... Yes. Of course :)

Comment: If you have lots of initializations, you should do it the other way around: do the initializations in a separate thread, and use the main thread to update the GUI (with a timer).

Comment: As pointed out already, a thread is not supposed to access the GUI (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655758/delphi-why-vcl-is-not-thread-safe-how-can-be) for more details).

Comment: Forgot to say: a benefit of doing the work in a separate thread and leaving the main thread idle is responsiveness. If you switch to another task and come back to your app, the GUI will not repaint itself because events are not processed.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25 you would need to show the splash screen from the main thread and then do all of the init work in the worker thread, syncing with the main thread if/when you want to update the UI, such as by showing init status in the splash screen. But you can't work with the VCL UI in a worker thread, it is simply not safe to do so, period. If you really want to do UI work in a worker thread, you would have to resort to direct Win32 API calls for that entire UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TApplication.MessageBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MessageBox) is a wrapper around the [WinAPI MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function.  The code for the former shows you how it's called :

```
function TApplication.MessageBox(const Text, Caption: PChar; Flags: Longint): Integer;
var
  ActiveWindow, TaskActiveWindow: HWnd;
  MBMonitor, AppMonitor: HMonitor;
  MonInfo: TMonitorInfo;
  Rect: TRect;
  FocusState: TFocusState;
  WindowList: TTaskWindowList;
begin
  ActiveWindow := ActiveFormHandle;
  if ActiveWindow = 0 then
    TaskActiveWindow := Handle
  else
    TaskActiveWindow := ActiveWindow;

   {  ... }


  try
    Result := Winapi.Windows.MessageBox(TaskActiveWindow, Text, Caption, Flags);
  finally
```

Notice that the HWND passed to the WinAPI call is `TaskActiveWindow`, which is taken as the active window at the time the call is made (unless there is none, in which case the application's handle is used instead).  Since you've just created your TFrmSplash, it will be the active window and the message box will be disposed when its parent (your splash window) is closed.

When you simply call MessageBox directly :

```
 MessageBox(Handle, 'Hi', nil, MB_OK);   // This remains on screen
```

You are passing `Handle`, which is implicitly the handle of the form from which you're calling the code, in this case your `TMainForm`, so the main form becomes the owner in this case and has no relation to the splash screen.

Comment: Man.... In the documentation, Embarcadeor says "The TApplication encapsulation of MessageBox automatically supplies the missing window handle parameter needed for the Windows API function". I thought it is better to use TApplication.MessageBox just because they will solve the missing handle problem. They "solved" it but entered some more murkiness to the problem.

Comment: In this case isn't cleaner to just use MessageBox(Handle, etc) ?

Comment: @Happy - Application.Messagebox is modal. Hard to imagine for the designers that you would take the owner window down from a thread!..

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25 you can show the MessageBox before starting the animation.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - I swear I wouldn't if the documentation would have mention that. Anyway, my mistake I haven't looked into MessageBox code. I inclined to think that the issue is in the bck thread and I looked into that instead. My fault!  ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe7/libraries/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MessageBox.html

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I haven't used that backgroundworker component, but I'd suspect the work completed event is queued to the main thread.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout - Nope. This is part of a much larger program. I want to create the splash screen AS SOON as possible and then, down the road I do all other initializations.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayDelphi_25 If you just want a simple solution, consider [ShowMessage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Dialogs.ShowMessage) instead.

Comment: @J...  I do want a nice and shiny box. This is why I use App.MessageBox. I have a lot of code around that. But anyway. Very nice catch! Thanks.

Comment: @J.. - Still it is able to run code asynchronously. One could do the same with a timer...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Indeed - I just mean to say that it may not be anything to do with non-deterministic behaviour due to breaking VCL cross-threading rules.